# ImageMagick escape character?

Tags: windows, command-line, character-encoding, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Is there an escape character I can use to pick up a copyright symbol in an ImageMagick *convert* command *label* directive?

I'm trying to mark a batch of images with a credit/copyright in the bottom-right corner. The batch is being handled by CMD script running in a Windows command line window. The problem I have is that the copyright symbol changes into a registered trademark symbol! I know it's a code page issue of going through the command window, so I'd hoped that ImageMagick could handle \Uxxxx or similar, but no joy.

Comment: Did you try a caret (`^`)?

Comment: Can you give an example `label:` directive?

Comment: Or use a UTF-8 encoded file with the contents in it and do `label:@file`

Comment: Unfortunately the caret didn't work for me. However, the label:@file approach would probably have been fine since the text would not be passing through the Windows command line and getting corrupted. In fact, since my copyright message is the same for all, this would seem to be a very sensible approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague found an answer involving temporarily changing code pages:

```
chcp 1252
set "c=©"
chcp 850
for %%f in (*.png) do convert -background "#FFFFFF" -font verdana -fill black label:" %c% 2015 My Company" miff:- | composite -gravity SouthEast -geometry +0+0 - "%%f" "credited\%%f.png"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If this is the correct answer for you, which I presume it is, please go ahead and mark it as correct so that other folks know it worked for you. You can accept it as the correct answer by clicking the hollow tick beside the vote counts. Enjoy SO - and remember questions are free!

Comment: Would love to but it says I can't accept my own answer for 2 days! Newbie probation?

Comment: Probaby - hang on in there and do it when you can. You may find your question and answer get upvoted which may give you the points to do so sooner :-)

Answer (score 3):

For windows command prompt (cmd), use the `^` symbol.

```
convert.exe label:^©copy example.png
```

[image: imagemagick escape character]

For power shell, this is ` symbol.

```
convert.exe label:`©copy example.png
```

> Note: For inserting the copyright symbol, I had to hold <kbd>alt</kbd> and type 0169 on the numberpad

Comment: Unfortunately this does work for me and I just get ^® in the image.